# Twitter button counting for only one page instead of website

Tags: jquery, button, twitter, web, count

I want to use **Twitter Count Button** for my website.

Here is the code which I am using...

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

But the problem is this button is counting for single page only means if I click on www.abc.com then it make the counter 1 but when I go on www.abc.com/xyz at this page it is 0. How to make this same for whole website.

Also Button counter is coming just after the button whileI want to use this counter box above the button so how to style it, I do not find this option on its [development site](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have inserted the button code manually on every page.

To sync it with all of your pages.

1. make a new .html file and add the twitter button code in it.
2. php include the twitter button .html in all of your pages like this.

   > ```
   > <?php 
   >             include ('twitterbutton.html')
   > ```
   >
   > ;>

add this php code in the div you want your button in. hopefully the counts will sync in all of your pages.

Comment: Actually I need this only homepage. On home page there is a pagination on first page if counter is 4 then on next page it is 0.while file is same for pagination and home.

Comment: could we see it live on your website?